# TideSDK - Show unread count (Icon Badges)

Tags: icons, tidesdk, dock

I intend to create a basic chat program with TideSDK. I was now wondering if it's possible to display new/unread message count in the dock/tray icon. For example, like this dock icon in OSX:

[image]

I did a quick search the docs but could not find anything about these so-called icon badges. Is this correct? My second thought was to update the entire dock/tray icon with a manually redrawn version to simulate badges. However, while I found API functions to update window icons I could also not find a way to update the main app icon.

Any ideas on how I could solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a pretty stupid question. Didn't realise the UI node could also be clicked in the doc navigation tree. The desired functionality is actually built-in. See the relevant doc page here: http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.UI

You have the following methods to achieve the desired or related result:

- Ti.UI.setBadge(txt)
- Ti.UI.setBadgeImage(imageURL)
- Ti.UI.setDockIcon(icon)